# How to import css file as local scoped in ReactJS?

Tags: css, reactjs, create-react-app

How can I import stylesheet locally for single view.

I am having two views `/home` and `/blog` and the following directory of files:

```
src
│  
└───components       
      │
      └───Home
      │     Home.js
      │     Home.css
      └───Blog
            Blog.js
            Blog.css
```

I have a seperate css file *home.css* for **home** view only but that style is getting applied to **blog** view also.

I want the *home.css* file to work only with the *home.js* view.

***Home.css***

```
.text1 {
   font-size: 1em !important;
   font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif !important;
   color: red;
 }
```

***Home.js***

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./home.css";

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="text1" style={{ overflow: "Hidden" }}>
        <h1>This must be red.</h1>
        <a href="/blog">Go to Blog</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

***Blog.js***

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./blog.css";   //I didn't Import Home.css here and blog.css is and empty css file.

class Blog extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="text1" style={{ overflow: "Hidden" }}>
        <h1>This must be black.</h1>
        <a href="/">Go to Home</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Blog;
```

Here is the React App:

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/AzizStark/ReactStyleIssue/tree/master/?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: this is happening because of the same className being used in both blog and home. Whichever stylesheet get appends last will have the most effect. Either use different className or use id instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot locally scope CSS in React with pure/vanilla CSS.

In order to achieve locally scoped CSS,

you will have to make use of

***1) [CSS modules](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/),***

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import styles from "./blog.css";  

class Blog extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="text1" style={styles.blackDiv}>
        <h1>This must be black.</h1>
        <a href="/">Go to Home</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Blog;
```

***2) [CSS-in-JS/JSS](https://cssinjs.org/?v=v10.0.0) (using libraries such as [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/)).***

```
const Button = styled.button`
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 2px solid palevioletred;
  color: palevioletred;
  margin: 0 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
`



render(
   <Button /> 
);
```

***3) Using [SASS/SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/guide)*** (by nesting the selectors/classes within a parent class)

```
// blog.scss

.blackDiv {
  >h1 {
    // css properties
  }
  > a {
     // css properties
  }
}
```

Comment: Why I cannot locally scope css?

Comment: @AzizStark that is because of how CSS works. Once CSS is imported, it will be "combined" and applied to the entire DOM.

Comment: You are right!, The CSS is combined. During the final build the css is bundled together even though I use "require()"function which only works is development environment.

Comment: @wentjun I thought webpack/css plugin adds some random string after the css class to keep it unique. Isn't it? I remember having same classes in different files and it still used to work in an isolated fashion.

Answer (score 10):

for locally scope don't use import, use require :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
//import "./home.css"; // comment

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    require("./home.css"); // here
    return (
      <div className="text1" style={{ overflow: "Hidden" }}>
        <h1 class="red">This must be red.</h1>
        <a href="/blog">Go to Blog</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Surprising this isn't said often, even though this is the easiest and best fix.