# Why both tables of different component JS file with different CSS files importing are giving same style?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

ExpenseEntryList.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './ExpenseEntryItemList.css';
import FormattedDate from './FormattedDate';
import FormattedMoney from './FormattedMoney';

const ExpenseEntryItemList = ({ items }) => {
  const lists = items.map((item) => (
    <tr key={item.id}>
      <td>{item.name}</td>
      <td>
        <FormattedMoney value={item.amount} />
      </td>
      <td>
        <FormattedDate value={item.spenddate} />
      </td>
      <td>{item.category}</td>
    </tr>
  ));

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Item</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Category</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>{lists}</tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

export default ExpenseEntryItemList;
```

ExpenseEntryItemList.css:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid violet;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid pink;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

th {
  background-color: aqua;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background-color: yellow;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background-color: orange;
}

caption {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

MovieBooking.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import FormattedDate from './FormattedDate';
import FormattedMoney from './FormattedMoney';
import './MovieBooking.css';
const MovieBooking = ({ items }) => {
  const lists = items.map((item) => (
    <tr key={item.id}>
      <td>{item.name}</td>
      <td>
        <FormattedMoney value={item.amount} />
      </td>
      <td>
        <FormattedDate value={item.spenddate} />
      </td>
      <td>{item.language}</td>
    </tr>
  ));

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Movie</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Language</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>{lists}</tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

export default MovieBooking;
```

MovieBooking.css:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid brown;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

th {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

 tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background-color: aqua;
}

 tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background-color: orange;
}

caption {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

FormattedDate.js:

```
import React from 'react';

const FormattedDate = ({ value }) => {
  const format = (value) => {
    const months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    const parsedDate = new Date(Date.parse(value));
    const formattedDate = `${parsedDate.getDate()}-${months[parsedDate.getMonth()]}-${parsedDate.getFullYear()}`;
    return formattedDate;
  };

  return <span>{format(value)}</span>;
};

export default FormattedDate;
```

FormattedMoney.js:

```
import React from 'react';

const FormattedMoney = ({ value }) => {
  const format = (amount) => {
    return parseFloat(amount).toFixed(2);
  };

  return <span>{format(value)}</span>;
};

export default FormattedMoney;
```

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import MovieBooking from './components/MovieBooking';
import ExpenseEntryItemList from './components/ExpenseEntryItemList';
function App() {
  const items = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Mango Juice",
      amount: 100,
      spenddate: "2020-10-10",
      category: "Food",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Assam Tea",
      amount: 1000,
      spenddate: "2020-10-11",
      category: 'Food',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Petrol",
      amount: 3000,
      spenddate: "2020-10-14",
      category: 'Travel',
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Bulb",
      amount: 140,
      spenddate: "2020-10-16",
      category: 'Electronic',
    }
  ];

  const movies=[
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Top Gun: Maverik",
      amount: 300.00,
      spenddate: "2022-06-21",
      language: "English",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Drishyam 2",
      amount: 250,
      spenddate: "2022-12-27",
      language: 'Hindi',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Pushpa",
      amount: 250,
      spenddate: "2021-12-14",
      language: 'Telegu',
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "The Balkan Line",
      amount: 140,
      spenddate: "2019-10-16",
      language: 'Russian',
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <div id='Expenses'>
        <h1 >Expense Items:</h1>
        <ExpenseEntryItemList items={items} />
      </div>
      <div id='Movies'>
        <h1>Movies: </h1>
        <MovieBooking items={movies}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

App.css:

```
#Expenses h1 {
  color: red;
}

#Movies h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

All files except App.js and App.css are in components folder. App.js and App.css are in src folder.

In the above code, I tried to import the "ExpenseEntryItemList.js" and "MovieBooking.js" file into App.js and tried to show them on a single webpage. Both of them showed the data in the form of a table.

I wanted to keep the styles of the table different. So, I made 2 CSS files one for each JS file component, and imported them to the respective JS files.

The table styles are absolutely the same!

Comment: This is because of how CSS works in React. Once CSS is imported, it gets 'combined' and applied to the entire DOM. If you want local scope CSS, you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59490701/how-to-import-css-file-as-local-scoped-in-reactjs

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.